# pipe a command not printing newline (but using \r)

Tags: bash, pipe, carriage-return

I want to pipe the output of a program that doesn't print newline, as it uses carriage return to replace it's line with new content.

this code represents the behavior of the program I'd like to retreive the output.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash                                                             

for i in {1..100};do                                                            
    echo -ne "[ $i% ] long unneeded log\r"                                            
    sleep 0.3                                                                   
done
```

i'd like , in a bash script, to cut this output live to display only the important info,
but as the program doesn't prints newline a `./program | awk ...` shows the output only when the command is ended.

I cannot modify the program that gives this output I'm trying to trim.
(I don't have it's source + I want to share my own script with other users)

I know my request is pretty specific, but is there a way to pipe the output character by character instead that by line?

Comment: Can you use script. like https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/61833/57293 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it thanks to a mix of @OznOg answer and @Walter-A link.

indeed replacing carriage returns with newline with `tr` works,
but it is buffered by default, [stdbuf](https://linux.die.net/man/1/stdbuf) can unbuffer it with `stdbuf -o0`.

so the final command is:

```sh
./program | stdbuf -o0 tr '\r' '\n' |  awk -F'[][]' '{printf $2 "\r"}'
```

this indeed prints live the first match between brackets, with a carriage return.

so a live log from the program showing on a single updated line `[x%] long compile detail` would be abbreviated just to `x%`, still using 1 line.

Comment: I'lll accept my answer once I'll have it tested at work in my script, that also does tricky things with the output.

Answer (score 1):

you may try

```
./program | tr '\r' '\n'
```

you may continue piping with a third program that would process line per line.

Answer (score -1):

Change your echo command from:

```
echo -ne
```

To:

```
echo -e
```

From the echo docs:

```
‘-n’
     Do not output the trailing newline.
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer, it made me realize I wasn't clear in my question, I can't modify my program that outputs carriage returns. I edited my question accordingly